# Purity affinity Victory

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I don't see the Promised Land in my victory tab in my game but the other victory option is available to play.

And I don't know what's wrong with my game that I can't see the Promised Land victory

Comment: Did you maybe disable the victory by unchecking it in the advanced options?  Usually all the possible victory conditions are always in the quests, regardless of what way you've chosen to play.

Comment: Have you installed any mods that may have broken it?

Answer (score 1):

As [agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86) suggests it is possible that you did not select this particular victory condition when creating the game.

It may also be possible that you have not completed the prerequisite technologies, if that's what you mean by not "seeing" the victory.  If this is incorrect and more details are provided, I or someone else could give you a more accurate answer.